# Excel 2007 forms to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, forms, excel, ado, synchronization

I've been searching everywhere for an answer with no success to the problem I'll describe.

I have an Excel sheet which gets manually updated frequently. I've been asked to push every row change into an Sql Server, in a live way. I need users to be able to save a row to the server by pushing a save button.

In SSMS I've been able to read data from the server using OPENROWSET, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\tmp\test2.xlsm',
'SELECT * FROM [myrng]');
```

I've been also able to insert data from Excel to SQL Server:

```
Insert into NEWDB.dbo.master 
Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 
12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\tmp\test2.xlsm','SELECT * FROM [myrng]')
```

The problem arises when I try to QUERY, INSERT or UPDATE data back to the server with the Excel file still open.

What I'm planning to do in the end is to build a wizard app to fill an Excel table which at the end of the process could be submitted to a corresponding SQL Server table.

I've been playing with VBA and ADO with no success so far, and I've been suggested to use DTS or SSIS, but I need the Excel file to stay open all the time.

Thanks in advance,
Rodrigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run against a connection to Excel:

```
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

''Late binding, so no reference is needed

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

cn.Open strCon

''A single value, but a query with parameters would be  better
ssql = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Test].table_1 (Atext ) " _
& "Values ('" & Sheet1.[b3] & "')"

cn.Execute ssql
```

Or

```
ssql = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server;" _
    & "Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Test].table_1 ( Atext ) " _
    & "SELECT ACol FROM [Sheet1$b7:c9]"
```

Or

```
ssql = "INSERT INTO [ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=server;" _
    & "Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=Test].table_1 ( Atext ) " _
    & "SELECT Acol FROM Anamedrange"
```

If HDR=No, use F1, F2 etc for the names of the various columns, numbering from the first column in the range.

This also works for me in Excel, for this example I used a reference to the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x library, but late binding would work just as well.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cn.Open servercon

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

cmd.CommandText = "insert_user" ''Stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Parameters("@username").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2)
cmd.Execute
```

Comment: I ended up doing that with a named range too. Thanks.